# Symfony2: simple rewrite rule in vhost to strip .html extention out

Tags: apache, symfony, mod-rewrite

Since I migrated my project on `Symfony2`, I also avoided to use `.html` extensions previously used for my generated urls.
So, after looking at some examples, I'am trying to execute this in my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [NC,L]
    #this is the standard rewrite rule to redirect every request to /web/app.php  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

I have tried many combinations but no one seems to work. Any Help? Thanks